# Creación de una cuadricula de div

Tags: html, css

Hola quiero crear una cuadricula de 3x3 `div`que estén todos bien posicionados.
Al principio he pensado en crear un `div`principal y que dentro de estos haya 9 `div`el problema viene cuando me pone los `div` siempre uno por debajo del otro. Lo que yo quiero es conseguir una tabla de 3x3 y que dentro pueda añadir una foto y un texto pequeñito sin que se me deforme la cuadricula. He probado de mil maneras y siempre se me acaba deformando. Pido una ayudita a ver si puedo solucionarlo, gracias.

```css
.prueba{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 70%;
    border:solid;
}
.prueba1{
    border:solid;
    margin-right: 40%;
    margin-left:35%;
}
.prueba2{
    border:solid;
    margin-left:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
        <div class="prueba">1</div>
        <div class="prueba1">2</div>
        <div class="prueba2">3</div>
        <div class="prueba">3</div>
        <div class="prueba1">4</div>
        <div class="prueba2">5</div>
        <div class="prueba">6</div>
        <div class="prueba1">7</div>
        <div class="prueba2">7</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Estas usando algun framework?

Comment: Desconozco que es eso,soy nuevo en la creación de webs...

Comment: No tienes ninguna restricción para usarlo? Si es así te recomiendo usar bootstrap creo que te ayudara ya que tiene un grid integrado por decirlo así. Este te puede ayudar mucho te paso la documentación https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Comment: te aconsejo que veas bien como funcionan los tags html, es decir las diferencias entre ellos, eso te ayudarà bastante, el problema que señalaste `"se me muestran un div abajo del otro"` es por el display que tiene por default el tag `div`, que hace en modo que se vizualize en bloque (ocupa toda la linea/ancho) para que esten uno al lado del otro tendrias que usar en css `div { display:inline-block }` y ajustarlo a tu gusto con `width` y `height` [aca][https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp] vas a encontrar puntos interesantes para mejorar, ☺

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar **CSS Grid**, es perfectamente dirigido a este tipo de diseños; y no requieres mucho codigo CSS, de igual manera es altamanete ajustable de modo que puedes modificarlo a como mejor te parezca.

Simplemente necesitas un contenedor principal al cual aplicas la propiedad `display: grid`, con esto todos los elementos hijos se comportaran como `grid-items` y puedes aplicarle las propiedades que necesites para tu cuadricula.

- `grid-template-columns`: Cantidad de columnas
- `grid-auto-rows`: Tamaño de las filas
- `grid-gap`: Espacio entre elementos de la cuadricula

Existen muchas mas propiedades que puedes utilizar para modificar el diseño, aqui te dejo una guía para que te familiarices mejor con CSS Grid:

https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2018/01/30/maquetacion-con-css-grid/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(80px, auto);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

Ejemplo con contenido:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(80px, 80px);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item img,
.grid-item p,
.grid-item h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <h1>Un titulo grande</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450" />
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta sin embargo al igual que el otro usuario deberías explicar que hace el código que pones para que sea más entendible a todo aquel que consulte

Comment: Pero si juego con px en el tamaño de los div dependiendo de la resolución de la pantalla se verán de una manera u de otra no?Yo suelo usar % por eso. De hecho no con grid pero ya me  ha pasado de poner cosas con px y luego abrirlo desde otra pantalla y verlo todo diferente.

Comment: En realidad el punto de Grid es no complicarte mucho definiendo tamaños... Si, puedes manejar los tamaños en dependencia de la pantalla con `px` pero existe tambien la unidad que utilizo en el ejemplo: `1fr`, esto define que el elemento deberia usar 1 fraccion del espacio total disponible y que se repita en 3 columnas... puedes solo cambiar estos valores para que sean menos o mas columnas en otras pantallas, siempre utilizaran "una fraccion del espacio que haya disponible"... Incluso intenta solo cambiar `repeat(3, 1fr)` y ponle 4 o 5 y veras como el grid si ajusta solo

Comment: Tambien existe otra opcion que es `auto-fill` o `auto-fit`; estas sirven para que el grid ajuste el numero de columnas por si solo, pero seria bueno que investigaras esas propiedades para comprenderlas mejor, ya que se comportan un poco diferente.. Si te fijas solo uso pixeles para definir el espacio entre los elementos y una altura minima para las cajas para que sean visibles

Comment: Primero de todo muchas gracias por tu explicación, llamame lelo pero a lo que yo me refiero es que, por ejemplo si el div es de 30cm x 30cm cuando inserto algo cambia el tamaño y hace que los otros se vuelvan pequeños y lo que yo quiero es que el tamaño del div no varíe y se quede siempre igual y le ponga lo que le ponga dentro no deje que eso varíe.

Comment: Eso es perfectamente posible, simplemente tienes que ser especifico, sin embargo no entiendo bien tu caso; si usas % entonces el tamaño cambia en dependencia de la pantalla, si quieres que tengan un tamaño maximo simplemente lo defines en cada elemento, entonces no se cual comportamiento esperas exactamente... En este caso basta con decirle a cada columna que su altura maximo sera digamos 30px y listo, luego al contenido de adentro simplemente le dices que ocupe el 100% de su contenedor; como explico la otra respuesta

Comment: @winnie añadi un ejemplo mas a la respuesta con los elementos con contenido dentro, fijate como se mantiene el tamaño de la cuadricula, a exepcion del ancho claro ya que esta definido para utilizar una porcion del espacio disponible

Comment: @IvanS95 perdona las molestias, pero si yo pongo dentro del div una imagen pero no quiero que ocupe todo sino solo una parte, si pongo por ejemplo una imagen de 640x480 luego si cambio de monitor eso me va a variar o siempre se va a ver igual dentro del div porque este se "amolda" a la pantalla? Porque si pongo por ejemplo la img quiero que la imagen se vea bien pero mas pequeña. Si pongo `width:100%;` se ve bien pero como hago para que se siga viendo bien y solo ocupe el 30% con un margen left de un 60% aprox.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91925/discussion-between-ivans95-and-winnie).

Answer (score 3):

Lo principal es el `css`. Básicamente le puse un tamaño de un **30%** del total a cada div, y los mostre tipo tabla con `display: table;`, ademas de flotarlos a la izquierda con `float: left;`

```css
.divCuadricula{
  width:30%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1%;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: 80px;
}
.divCuadricula img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% ;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <div class="divCuadricula"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/"></img></div>
  <div class="divCuadricula"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/"></div>
  <div class="divCuadricula"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/"></div>
  <div class="divCuadricula"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/"></div>
  <div class="divCuadricula"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/"></div>
  <div class="divCuadricula"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/"></div>
  <div class="divCuadricula"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/"></div>
  <div class="divCuadricula"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/"></div>
  <div class="divCuadricula"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/16:9x1080/"></div>
</div>
```

---

Para que los valores de adentro no tomen cualquier valore y rompan la estructura, les tienes que decir q tomen tanto el `width` como el `height` de el div donde estan. Para eso hacen falta estas lineas:

```
.divCuadricula img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% ;
}
```

Comment: Esto funciona así con un numero dentro pero en cuanto le pongo contenido(foto,texto etc...) dentro ya se deforma y es a lo que me refería con mi pregunta.

Comment: No, probablemente pusiste algo adentro que supera el tamaño que tiene el div, y por eso se agranda y se va para abajo. Para eso puedes, o bien ponerle un máximo al div, o a lo que pones dentro, decirle q use como máximo el ancho del div.